# Today's shaping up to be a good day - meaning

Tags: phrase-meaning, idioms

**Today's shaping up to be a good day.**

I looked up what shaping up means. I think it means, the sentence, today's turning into a good day. Am I right?

And, does **today's shaping into a good day** mean the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"To shape up" is informal for "to develop" or "to turn into":

[Cambridge English Dictionary definition](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/shape-up)

It carries a nuance of "in my opinion" and/or "contrary to my expectation."

"Shape up" is a phrasal verb; you can't drop the "up." So your second sentence is ungrammatical. Another common way to say the same thing is:

> Today's looking like it's going to be a good day.

With many variations.

Comment: Does shape into mean the same thing? Like, could I say "today's shaping into a good day."?

Comment: No, but you can say “shape up into,” as in, “He’s shaping up into a great leader.” This is a very informal expression.